# Is there a way to get equivalent of a user-identity token in Word or Excel add-in?

Tags: office-addins, onedrive

The Javascript API for Office includes a method Mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/fp142236.aspx) which can be used to authenticate to other systems. I'm not seeing any equivalent in Word and Excel.  What I'd like to be able to do is get a token which can be used to get additional metadata about the document, for example, the size of the file using the O365 REST API. From a Word or Excel online add-in I can get the URL but that's about it.  Is it possible to do this without sending the user through a separate OAuth workflow?